# Make the backdrop a url on a chromecast?

Tags: chromecast

Is it possible to make the backdrop home screen thing that the chrome casts display when they are not casting anything, a URL of a website? It would make it a lot easier for what i am doing if it was possible.

I know that you can connect your google+ photo library and a few other things, but no where have i seen that i can use a URL, i highly doubt it but i thought i'd ask. I have tried looking through the backdrop preferences but couldn't find a URL option. The FAQ doesn't mention this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, developers do not have access to that area outside of the few options that you had mentioned (which can be accessed and set from the Google Home app).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of getting rid of the name of the Chromecast from the backdrop screen? You can get rid of things like the clock, weather but is it possible for there to be no watermark like thing over the top?

Comment: Backdrop is not something that developers can modify; it is for the user and there is a reason for the chromecast name to be there. So in short, you cannot modify it to not show the name.